# listreceivedbyaddress does not return any information about change addresses, is there any alternative?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli, change

[`listreceivedbyaddress`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/listreceivedbyaddress/) does not return info about change addresses (m/84'/1'/0'/1/*)
, only about receiving addresses (m/84'/1'/0'/0/*). I've found out that [`getreceivedbyaddress` "address"](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/getreceivedbyaddress/) shows info about both change and receive addresses.

The issue is that the output of `listreceivedbyaddress` is more complete than that of `getreceivedbyaddress`, with an array of txids of all receiving addresses of the wallet whereas `getreceivedbyaddress` shows only the received amount of the specified by the user address.

How might one get the received transactions of all change and receiving addresses?